# Images not lining up where they should be?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, fluid-layout

I have searched around for an answer but cant seem to find anything(maybe im using the wrong keywords). I am using Bootstrap with the following grid system. 22 grids, each 47px wide, with a margin of 0 between each grid.This means for every 4 grids I have a total of 188px. Each 4 grids contain two images a 1px vertical bar and one 187px logo.

This should be enough to display both images side by side but the logos keep getting kicked down. If I put  `class="pull-left"` on the vertical bars the logos will go back to where they are supposed to be until I size down my browser window the smallest amount to make the fluid rows resize.

At first I thought it maybe was just a tolerance/rounding issue with the columns so I made my images 5px smaller but that did not change anything. Any ideas of what may be causing this or how to fix it? The only css applied to this is the standard `bootstrap.css` style sheet and a maximum body width of 1040px.

```
<div class="row-fluid ">
    <div class="span4 offset1">
        <img src="img/verticalBar.jpg">
        <img src="img/logo1.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
        <img src="img/verticalBar.jpg">
        <img src="img/logo2.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
        <img src="img/verticalBar.jpg">
        <img src="img/logo3.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
        <img src="img/verticalBar.jpg">
        <img src="img/logo4.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
        <img src="img/verticalBar.jpg">
        <img src="img/logo5.jpg">
        <img src="img/verticalBar.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

This is what the page currently looks like. The red arrows indicate where the logos are supposed to go. 
[image]

Comment: can you please show the test page ?

Comment: I uploaded this to a domain I had laying around. http://costumepuppy.com/

Comment: looks perfect to me .. on ff

Comment: Did you try resizing the window? As soon as your resize it, the images do not scale correctly forcing them down like the images above.

Comment: Did ya customized bootstrap in any way . Secondly I dont see bootstrap-responsive.css in your html . Plus bootstrap already normalize ,, why a seperate normalize file.

Comment: I used the customize feature on the bootstrap website. This also why there is no bootstrap-responzive.css. When you use the customize feature on the bootstrap website it essentially bundles the two files together and then all you need is the meta tag.  As far as the normalize file.... I really don't know. When I was first beginning to learning bootstrap my instructor said "hey put this in" so I did and now it has been in every project since(embarrassed face).

Comment: I have found that if use a class on my logos `.logo { display:block; margin: 0 auto; max-width: 99%}` and then float the `verticalBar.jpg` It seems to work. It makes me a little frustrated because I feel as if I should be able to make it work without css.

Comment: Hmmmm still working this out

Answer (score -1):

Try adding this to your css:

```
html, body, div, span, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q,      samp, small, strong, b, i, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, table, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, footer, header, nav, section {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  border:0;
  outline:0;
  font-size:100%;
  vertical-align:baseline;
  background:transparent;
}
```

Comment: That did not work :( Its not a problem with padding/border/margin. I am pretty sure it has something to do with the way the columns are resizing the logo images.